# Wordpress Htaccess problem with subfolder

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have to install a program in a subdirectory of a site with WordPress.

I have already done the same thing on other sites with WordPress without any problems.

I have problems with this site, when I go to the page address it says "Page not Found". The site is "www.sogenit.com" and the subdirectory is "ecobonus". "www.sogenit.com/ecobonus"

I think it's a .htaccess problem Can someone help me?
Below I am attaching the contents of the `.htaccess` file

Content of File .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On #created by aruba do not touch this file!

#ATTENTION: Remove file index.(php|html|htm)

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/drupal/.*$

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /drupal/$1 [L]
```

Comment: This is not the WordPress .htaccess

Comment: Where is the `.htaccess` file located that you've posted? Do you have any other `.htaccess` files, perhaps in the parent/root directory?

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /subdirectory-name/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /subdirectory-name/index.php [L]
# END WordPress
```